# Bootstrap data-toggle disappears in browser

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, dropdown

Something strange is happening currently on a website I'm building.

I'm using opencart (in case this mathers) to build a new webshop.
The cart widget in top right is clickable so it will open showing the products currently in the shopping basket.

So, as it has to be done in bootstrap I've added the data-toggle="dropdown"

```
<div id="cart" class="btn-group btn-block">
    <button type="button" data-loading-text="<?php echo $text_loading; ?>" class="btn btn-inverse btn-block btn-lg dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
       <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> 
       <span id="cart-total"><?php echo $text_items; ?></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
        ...
    </ul>
</div>
```

But, when running it in the browser, the toggle part disappears and this is what I get from the Chrome inspector:

```
<button type="button" data-loading-text="Laden..." class="btn btn-inverse btn-block btn-lg dropdown-toggle"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> <span id="cart-total">0 product(en) - €0,00</span></button>
```

However, to make this even stranger (imo) a quick view on the source of that pages gives me this result:

```
 <button type="button" data-loading-text="Laden..." class="btn btn-inverse btn-block btn-lg dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> <span id="cart-total">0 product(en) - €0,00</span></button>
```

Chrome also isn't prompting any javascript issues so I'm getting a little frustrated on this one.

Comment: but i don't see any problem, even the data-toggle remains intact here [JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/k599eLvL/1/)

Comment: [link](http://phpscript.be)

It's the upper right button showing the cart icon, may I ask if it works from your side?

Comment: no it isn't working though...

Comment: its definitely due to the disapperaring data-toggle, check here, its working but you need the data-toggle attribute anyhow... [JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/hav0jwj5/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its the `$('.dropdown-toggle').removeAttr("data-toggle");` in ur **commons.js** file which is loading `on Page load` event. please remove it and try again.